# getting lastmodified date of image using HTML5 tag

Tags: javascript, android, html, ionic2

I have tried to use the HTML5 tag to capture image with smartphone (android, iOS, windows) camera or choose image from gallery. It is an ionic project, which has to run with web browser (without installing app on phone) on apache server.

```
<input id="camera" type="file" accept="image/*" >
```

Now I need to get the lastmodified date of gallery image to check the age of the images which is selected.

But I didn't find any working solution... can anyone help me?
It would be very nice...

Thanks so much!
Greetings

---edited---
Thanks for the solution:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById("myFileInput")
var file = fileInput.files[0]
var lastModified = fileInput.files[0].lastModified
```

But this doesn't work with iOS...

The content of file object (file) in...

OSX chrome:

```
{"0":{}}
```

android chrome:

```
{"0":{}}
```

safari iPhone:

```
{"0":{},"length":1}
```

I don't know why this object doesn't show more attributes... because on chrome for OSX and Android file.lastModified shows the date in ms.

is there anybody who can help out here?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's possible like so:

```
var fileInput = document.getElementById("myFileInput")
var file = fileInput.files[0]
var lastModified = fileInput.files[0].lastModified
```

Here's a fiddle:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j0jrcsoh/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply... But I think the problem is processing the images with this tag... you got blob file. Do you think it is possible to read the initially  date of images from this file?

Comment: Ran into something interesting. It might actually work for you even though it seems to be depreciated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/lastModifiedDate

Comment: Here's what you can do with blob: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: Seems like you can't do much client side. Only get name and file size... and that's basically it.. At least based on documentation

Comment: If there is any possibility to check the date from server side... it would not be any problem to first upload to server php script and get response by ajax or something else... but I don't think the created file has still the correct / original metadata.

Comment: I am afraid you are right. 
But, what are you trying to achieve? Maybe we can figure out a different way

Comment: I need to capture images with phone camera and select images from gallery. Then I will transfer to php script for save the pictures on server. capturing with camera is no problem because the images are "new". But I only need to allow select/transfer images from users phone gallery which are not older then xxx hours.

Comment: With an app like android you could simply do Files.readAttributes(). From web... maybe there is a way to filter file attributes just like you can filter formats... Let me dig around

Comment: Yes I know about native app functions... but in this case it is required to use web application. That's the problem. It would be nice if you can help me out..

Comment: Happy to help. We took a detour, but it paid off :)

Comment: I think... maybe I was pleased little bit too early.
On Android this works well, but on iOS it seems not to work :-(